# Plugin.Geolocator Authorization Error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I want to get the GPS location of my device. I am using **GeolocatorPlugin** for Xamarin to get the Longitude and Latitude of my device. GPS is enabled on my device. I already added permission to my android manifest but I still get the error: **"A geolocation error occured: Unauthorized"** How can I fix this?

```
try
{
   var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
   locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

    var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();
    entLocation.Text = position.Longitude.ToString() + "," + position.Latitude.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //will catch any general exception and set message in a string
    string msg = ex.Message;
    await DisplayAlert("error", msg, "ok");
}
```

Comment: Runtime permissions : https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/ There are Forms-based wrappers also, https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: For Marshmallow **and** above you have to ALSO request the permission at runtime so the user is able to accept or decline that permission as the manifest-based permission is only the first step on newer Android API levels

Comment: I have added the manifest permissions

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Refer the links in my first comment

Comment: where do I add public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the code below inside your MainActivity.cs in your Android Project.

```
if(CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)
{
    RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 0);
}
```